# keep button position on panel resize

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, panel

I've been messing around with something that should be simple.

I've moved jobs and trying to get some of the basic tools I have used before, but of course I don't have the old source to look at.

We had extended panel to have some standard properties and functions (save, close, save and close).

But I can't get the buttons to be positioned correctly on a resize.  I put this ExtPanel on a form but the buttons keep disappearing as I resize, or don't move as expected (frozen on bottom right).

The class

```
public partial class ExtPanel: UserControl
   {
   private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSaveandClose;
   private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnCancel;
   private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnSave;

   public ExtPanel ()
      {
      InitializeComponent ();
      }

// misc things this class does...


}

public partial class ExtPanel
    {
    private void InitializeComponent ()
       {
        this.btnSaveandClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnSave = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // btnSaveandClose
        // 
        this.btnSaveandClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(899, 689);
        this.btnSaveandClose.Name = "btnSaveandClose";
        this.btnSaveandClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.btnSaveandClose.TabIndex = 0;
        this.btnSaveandClose.Text = "Save and Close";
        this.btnSaveandClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnSaveandClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Click_SaveandClose);
        this.btnSaveandClose.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles) ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));

        // 
        // btnCancel
        // 
        this.btnCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(687, 689);
        this.btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel";
        this.btnCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.btnCancel.TabIndex = 1;
        this.btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
        this.btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnCancel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Click_Close);
        this.btnCancel.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles) ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));

        // 
        // btnSave
        // 
        this.btnSave.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(793, 689);
        this.btnSave.Name = "btnSave";
        this.btnSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 30);
        this.btnSave.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnSave.Text = "Save";
        this.btnSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnSave.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Click_Save);
        this.btnSave.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles) ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));

        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnSave);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnCancel);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnSaveandClose);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1008, 730);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // ExtPanel
        // 
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "ExtPanel";
        this.Size = this.panel1.Size;
        this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.click_this);
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;


}
```

Comment: What are your expectations for your panel?  You have it at 1008 by 730 pixels, so it's pretty large.  The buttons are current anchored to the bottom right of the panel.  Is the issue the panel's scrollbar always moving them off screen?

Comment: 1024 * 768 is pretty normal screen resolution, this panel is covering the whole form.  Instead of creating a base form, creating a base panel.  I can put a Panel in a Form, I can't put a Form in a TabControl. It let's my design be a little flexible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Have you tried anchoring the button?</strike>

...I missed the anchoring code.

If you have a button in the lower right-hand corner that you want to stay in the lower right-hand corner when resizing the form, set it's anchor properties to Bottom, Right.

**Update:**
I loaded your code. You have a panel inside of `ExtPanel`. If you dock (`Fill`) that panel then you should be working fine by resizing ExtPanel.